# Port forwarding 

Tags: networking, router, svn, port-forwarding

I want to set up a svn server on my computer, so it's available from anywhere.

I think I set up the repository correctly, using CollabSVN. If I go to Repo-Browser with TortoiseSVN and point it to `svn://localhost:3690`, it shows the proper repository.

The problem now is that I'm behind a router. My local IP is 192.168.1.45. Doing `svn://192.168.1.45:3690` also works. My global IP is, say, `x.x.x.x`. Just doing `svn://x.x.x.x:3690` doesn't work, which makes sense, since I have to set up port forwarding.

I'm using a Verizon router. Using their web interface (on `192.168.1.1`) I added the following port forwarding rule:

```
IP Address forward to: 192.168.1.45
Source Ports: Any
Dest Ports: 3690
Forward to: 3690
Protocol: TCP
```

However, even after applying this rule, going to `svn://x.x.x.x:3690` doesn't work. It takes a few seconds to fail, then says that the connection couldn't be established because the server connected to didn't respond properly after a period of time. What's interesting is that a random port, like `svn://x.x.x.x:36904` fails immediately, saying that the target machine actively refused the connection. So I figure that the forwarding rule did *something*, but not fully what was necessary.

Any ideas on how to get this working? The router model is `MI424-WR` and the firmware version is `4.0.16.1.56.0.10.12.3`.

UPDATE: I also tried setting destination port to 45000, and still forwarding to 3690, in case something was wrong w/ the lower-numbered ports, but to no avail. I also tried port 80 to port 3690, still all in vain.

Comment: Are you using the Westell 7500?

Comment: not quite. i noticed the instructions on verizon's site, and although the interface looks similar, the port forwarding part was different

Comment: Well our company has about 50 locations that have DSL and we received the 7500 Verizon router. Since day 1 they had nothing but issues with port forwarding. We swapped them out for 6110 bridge only modems and Netgear routers because they had so many issues.

Comment: hm it could just be router fail. i remember getting port 80 to forward properly, though.. i wonder why this one doesnt.

Comment: check this post (http://serverfault.com/questions/71775/setting-up-subversion-server-on-windows-2008-access-when-ports-blocked)

Answer (score 1):

Many routers don't support this, but if you try it from outside your internal network it will work.

Ask a friend to try that svn://x.x.x.x:3690 from somewhere else on the internet and see if it works, or if you have a shell account somewhere, ssh to there and try to svn ls svn://x.x.x.x:3690

I don't know the name for this firewall feature. I do know that making linux do it (which is what your wrt54gl uses) is a matter of adding an SNAT rule along with the DNAT rule.

There is a VERY good explanation here : http://security.maruhn.com/iptables-tutorial/x9305.html

Answer (score 0):

Try forwarding on both TCP and UDP.  Some quick research showed that SVN uses both.

Comment: i tried that earlier and it didn't work. i just re-added it, since it seems like i'll need it anyway, but the same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first test if the port forwarding is working, by creating a forwarding rule for [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) (remote desktop protocol) on some Windows machine. (Forward 3389 TCP form outside to 3389 and IP address of Windows machine.) After creating the rule, test the you can connect to the Windows machine using remote desktop connection. (Or you could try to forward SSH, it's just for testing.)

Also, your router may be behind a modem, and if so, make sure you forward from the modem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server has a firewall blocking the request or the svn has a config that makes it listen only to localhost.
Try accessing it from a local pc with the private address of the server.
If it still doesn't work it's most likely a firewall.
If you are using windows try to stop the firewall and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

many router don't support connecting to your self using your ext. ip address if you want to see if the server is working from outside try http://canyouseeme.org/ just type in your port and it will tell you if people can connect from the outside or not